# Error in php while trying to send email

Tags: php, html, email

I am learning php and have a book which has lots of examples and exercises in. The one I'm doing is about sending email. I copied the code to the letter, but I am getting an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\website2\www\sendscript.php on line 6
```

Why is this happening, any idea?

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php
    if(($_POST['sender_name']=="")||($_POST['sender_email']=="")||($_POST['message']=="")){
        header("Location: sendemail.html");
        exit;
    }

    $email = "Sender's name:\t$_POST['sender_name']\n";
    $email .= "Sender's email:\t$_POST['sender_email']\n";
    $email .= "Message:\t$_POST['message']\n";
    $to = "stafford.king16@pgs.org.uk";
    $subject = "did script work?";
    $mailheaders = "From: Stafford King";
    $mailheaders .= "Reply to: $_POST['sender_email']\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $email, $mailheaders);
?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Email sent!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my email input form:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form method = "post" action = "sendscript.php">
        <p><strong>Your name:</strong><br />
        <input type = "text" name = "sender_name" size = "30"</p>
        <p><strong>Your email address:</strong><br />
        <input type = "text" name = "sender_email" size = "30"</p>
        <p><strong>Message:</strong><br />
    <textarea name = "message" cols = "30" rows = "5" wrap = "virtual"></textarea></p>
        <p><input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "send email"></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Not to crap on OP's dreams, but this question doesn't deserve up-votes. It's a parse/syntax error, simple as that. Had OP used a proper IDE none of us would have ever seen this question because it would never have been an issue.

Comment: Its my choice what I use, and the point of this site is to ask questions. If i had used an IDE, it would just have squiggly red underlined it and given me the same error. So shut up

Comment: It's also your prerogative to use the butt end of a screwdriver to push a nail into wood. It works, but that doesn't mean you're doing it right.

Comment: U don't use a screwdriver to knock in a nail - theres this tool called a hammer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to wrap your array variables in curly brackets `{}` or concatenate them within the string:

**OPTION 1**

```
$email = "Sender's name:\t{$_POST['sender_name']}\n";
```

**OPTION 2**

```
$email = "Sender's name:\t" . $_POST['sender_name'] . "\n";
```

**NOTE:**

Use of an IDE such as Dreamweaver (license fee), NetBeans or Eclipse (both open source & free) would have caught this immediately. Try one of these, rather than Notepad or Notepad++.

Comment: @gd1 both are valid, though (as you correctly point out) option 2 is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

```
$email = "Sender's name:\t$_POST['sender_name']\n";
```

can't be resolved very well. Use

```
$email = "Sender's name:\t{$_POST['sender_name']}\n";
```

instead. Alternatively, you could concatenate or use `sprintf`:

```
$email = "Sender's name:\t" . $_POST['sender_name'] . "\n";
$email = sprintf("Sender's name:\t%s\n", $_POST['sender_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split up your concatenation:

```
$email = "Sender's name:\t" . $_POST['sender_name'] . "\n";
$email .= "Sender's email:\t" . $_POST['sender_email'] . "\n";
$email .= "Message:\t" . $_POST['message'] . "\n";
```

PHP can't parse it as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the variables in curly braces or taking them out of the double quotes will help with the body of the email but not solve your parsing error. You mail headers seem to be messed up. You need a "\n" at the end of the each line. Change the first $mailheader assignment to: `$mailheaders = "From: Stafford King\n";`